# Render compressed png from music21

Tags: python, music21

When I'm trying to save score as a png,

```py
sc = stream.Part()
...
sc.write('musicxml.png')
```

it sometimes get rendered as follows:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise  PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 3.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise version="3.0">
  <movement-title />
  <identification>
    <creator type="composer" />
    <encoding>
      <encoding-date>2020-11-19</encoding-date>
      <software>music21 v.6.1.0</software>
    </encoding>
  </identification>
  <defaults>
    <scaling>
      <millimeters>7</millimeters>
      <tenths>40</tenths>
    </scaling>
  </defaults>
  <part-list>
    <score-part id="P8729564f570fa991172c7cf3dc206c44">
      <part-name />
    </score-part>
  </part-list>
  <!--=========================== Part 1 ===========================-->
  <part id="P8729564f570fa991172c7cf3dc206c44">
    <!--========================= Measure 0 ==========================-->
    <measure number="0">
      <attributes>
        <divisions>10080</divisions>
        <time>
          <beats>6</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
        </time>
      </attributes>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>G</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <notations>
          <slur type="start" number="1" />
        </notations>
      </note>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>C</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>B</step>
          <alter>-1</alter>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <accidental>flat</accidental>
      </note>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>F</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <notations>
          <slur type="stop" number="1" />
        </notations>
      </note>
      <note>
        <rest />
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
      </note>
    </measure>
    <!--========================= Measure 0 ==========================-->
    <measure number="0">
      <attributes>
        <time>
          <beats>3</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
        </time>
      </attributes>
      <note>
        <pitch>
          <step>G</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>20160</duration>
        <type>half</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <chord />
        <pitch>
          <step>C</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>20160</duration>
        <type>half</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <chord />
        <pitch>
          <step>B</step>
          <alter>-1</alter>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>20160</duration>
        <type>half</type>
        <accidental>flat</accidental>
      </note>
      <note>
        <chord />
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>20160</duration>
        <type>half</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <chord />
        <pitch>
          <step>F</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
        </pitch>
        <duration>20160</duration>
        <type>half</type>
      </note>
      <note>
        <rest />
        <duration>10080</duration>
        <type>quarter</type>
      </note>
    </measure>
  </part>
</score-partwise>
```

I would like to compress it, so redundant spaces will be removed:
[image]

**Is it somehow possible to force music21 toolkit to compress my score, so it wont take whole screen?**

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Above warning is some kind of bullshit..

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `music21.layout` docs and module to see how to set SystemLayout and PageLayout objects to specify the width of the page and where to do line/system breaks to get the output you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I can't see `stretch` anywhere in there.